# Different buttons with same id

Tags: android, button

I just wanted to know if my application will work fine if two buttons in different activities have the same id. What are the possible complications that can arise due to this.

Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes , you can use same id in two different activities. In fact, it may be good practice to.

If in the same layout, you won't be able to create a duplicate id.

**Edit**

AFAIK you can use the same id in different activities because when you

```
setContentView(R.layout.splash);
```

and inflate layout then android itself searches for that particular id in that particular layout so no problem here.

Answer (score 1):

If Buttons are in different activities, no complications at all there, but when Buttons are in the same activities, then findViewById, will return button declared latest in xml, will be returned.

In fact, If you would declare some view with same ids, in different xml, then generated R would have lesser Variables in it.

Answer (score 1):

There will be no complications. Your app will work fine as far as they are in different activities.

When ever you create a resource say a Button it will be registered in the R.java with its own id something like,

```
  public static final int button=0x7f03002b;
  public static final int button1=0x7f03002c;
```

So this will be unique and you will have no problem.